# Sending mail only once in a stored procedure SQL Server executed by scheduled task

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks, sendmail

I have a SQL Server stored procedure, which runs via a scheduled task every 7 minutes, and which is used to send an email to the recipients concerned, once the condition of the number of records returned by request is greater than or equal to 1.

the procedure code is:

```
Begin

declare @recordCount int 
declare @bodytext varchar(200)


select @recordCount = isnull(count(*), 0)
from table where .............

IF (@recordCount > 0)
set @bodytext = N'Message'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Profile',
    @recipients = 'Test@test.com',
    @subject = 'Title',
    @Body = @bodytext,
    @query = N'Select Column1,Column2
                from Table 
                inner join Table2 on .........
                where ........................', 
    @execute_query_database = N'DB'

End
End;
```

My problem is that I'd like to send the email, only once, since the scheduled task runs every 7 minutes, but i can't find the track how i can achieve that without adding new columns in the "Table".

Comment: A simple way if you can't or don't want to add any additional state is to look in `sysmail_allitems` if you've already sent a mail within a particular period and return if you did. Of course you do need a way to distinguish that mail from others, but there are many ways to do so.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: After checking the email history in sysmail_allitems, I saw that in a period of 30 minutes, the email is sent 4 times with the same information, the only information that distinguishes the records is the mailitem_id. which has no correspondence in the code of the procedure.

Comment: Why do you need more distinguishing information? All you need to know is when the last mail was sent by your sproc (as opposed to any other) and that could easily be done by using a distinct profile or title or checking the query used (for that, it's probably best to start with a comment, as that's much simpler to check than the full text). You don't need to further distinguish individual mails as you only need the time the last one was sent and bail out if it isn't far enough in the past.

Comment: _...send the email, only once..._ Only once EVER? Or just once a day? something else?

Comment: I don't know your business needs, but we have solved this in next ways: a) by writing some fields (like e-mail timestamp) back into table itself (if one record needs to send exactly one mail) or b) by using some additional table, where sent mail information is stored.

Comment: @Arvo: are there other ways without resorting to the structure of the database.

Comment: @Freedom7 There are always many more ways :) I just wrote down, how we have solved such problems. For us tracking sent e-mails (often automatic invoices or order confirmations) is quite important - especially when some e-mails do not go through.

Comment: @SMor the scheduled task is executed every 7 minutes, and the sending of mail is conditioned by the number of records returned by the sql query and which have the status = 0 (this field is used for other needs). there is another scheduled task that runs every 30 minutes and updates new records by setting their status to 1 (so they won't be returned in the first sql query)